# Efficient methods for finding a basis for a set of pure tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space and {$t_i$} is a set of **pure tensors** in $V^{\otimes r}$, is there a more efficient way to find a basis for the linear span of {$t_i$} than the method that does not take into account the constraint of pure tensors?

I have tried to create a Gaussian-elimination-like method, but it doesn't seem to work because even with pure tensors having the form $v_1$$\otimes$$v_2$$\otimes\cdots\otimes$$v_r$, it is not possible to perform a row reduction on individual $V$ in a simple way.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.